# How to set permalink for post in blogger using PHP gdata library

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, blogger, gdata

i'm using php Gdata library to post to blogger using the following function
[Posting to Blogger using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284808/posting-to-blogger-using-php)

My question is how to customize post permalink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it by publishing the post with the permalink as the title then edit the post's title and replacing it by the real title

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$entry->permalink` attribute to set an address. I'm not sure if you should set it with the `.html` extension or not, so test it out.

---

Apparently the above is depreciated and doesn't work any more.

However this is version 1 of the Blogger API. I suggest migrating to the current version 3, which you can find out more about [on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using).

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Property _permalink ....

Comment: Like I say, it's a very old API. Use v3.

Comment: I got around it by publishing the post with the permalink as the title then edit the post's title and replacing it by the real title